# Android: testing location on device cloud

Tags: android, mobile, mobile-automation

Is there any mobile cloud testing service for Android offering enhanced location capabilities? My requirements are:

- Playback of recorded GPS/location data
- GPS data needs to be provided as 'real' data, not as (recognizable) mock data
- ARM only app, so emulators are probably not an option

I haven't found a service yet that offers location capabilities beyond setting a static location before each test run. Is there any service out there that meets my requirements?

Comment: Not really sure because I haven't used it personally, but maybe AWS Device Farm can help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

There's always an option called:

- Crowdtesting;

You can basically hire remote testers from a specific country which will have specific mobile devices. It will be quite cheap if you want to do for example one test case, or short exploratory testing session.

**You could create a test case that requires them to walk like 2km or something like that. It really depends on what you are searching for :)**

For example:

- http://www.utest.com/ | http://www.applause.com/
- http://trymyui.com/
- http://www.testbirds.com/
- http://www.usertesting.com/
- https://crowdsourcedtesting.com/
- https://mycrowd.com/
- https://test.io/
- http://testuj.pl
- https://usabilityhub.com/
- https://globalapptesting.com/
- https://www.digivante.com/
- https://we-are-testers.com/
- https://betafamily.com/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'd like to run automated tests.

Comment: Right, and forcing a device location by external GPS signal would be ok? Can you tell us a little more about that automated test? You need to force a specific path, or...?

Comment: Yes, as described in my question, I'd need to simulate a path. The location would need to come from the 'real' location provider (= not be regognizeable by the system as mocked location).